# How can i fetch data from a particular index in elasticsearch?

Tags: python, database, elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5

When i am trying to fetch data all i am getting is some useless information like datatype etc. How can I get the real data stored in the index.

```
{"rpa-trans-2020.02.26":{"aliases":{},"mappings":{"rpa-trans":{"dynamic":"true","properties":{"@timestamp":{"type":"date"},"@version":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"AreaImpacted":{"type":"keyword"},"AssigneeUserId":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"CreatedByUserId":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"CrossReferenceId":{"type":"keyword"},"EntityName":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"ErrorCode":{"type":"keyword"},"ErrorDescription":{"type":"keyword"},"FailureTransaction":{"type":"integer"},"Initiator":{"type":"keyword"},"InstanceId":{"type":"integer"},"IsApplication":{"type":"keyword"},"ListenerReqEndTime":{"type":"long"},"ListenerReqStartTime":{"type":"long"},"NotQualifiedRequest":{"type":"integer"},"Param1":{"type":"float"},"Param2":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"Param3":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"Param4":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"ProcessName":{"type":"keyword"},"Processes":{"type":"keyword"},"QualifiedRequest":{"type":"integer"},"RetryTrans":{"properties":{"ReasonRequestUnsuccessful":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"RetryAttemptNumber":{"type":"long"},"RetryReason":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}}}},"RobotReqEndTime":{"type":"long"},"RobotReqStartTime":{"type":"long"},"Robots":{"type":"keyword"},"SearchInput":{"type":"keyword"},"SourceApplicationId":{"type":"keyword"},"SourceMachineId":{"type":"keyword"},"StepDescription":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"StepEndTime":{"type":"date"},"StepStartTime":{"type":"date"},"StepStatus":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"SuccessfulTransaction":{"type":"integer"},"TransactionDateTime":{"type":"date","format":"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ"},"TransactionEndTime":{"type":"date"},"TransactionId":{"type":"keyword"},"TransactionMessage":{"type":"keyword"},"TransactionProcessName":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"TransactionProfileName":{"type":"keyword"},"TransactionSource":{"type":"keyword"},"TransactionState":{"type":"keyword"},"TransactionStatus":{"type":"keyword"},"TransactionTitle":{"type":"keyword"},"TransactionType":{"type":"keyword"},"UserId":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"elapsed_execution_time":{"type":"float"},"elapsed_execution_time  ":{"type":"float"},"elapsed_handle_time":{"type":"float"},"elapsed_qualification_time":{"type":"float"},"elapsed_qualification_time ":{"type":"float"},"elapsed_timestamp_start":{"type":"date"},"elapsed_wait_time":{"type":"float"},"manual_proc_time":{"type":"integer"},"process_sla":{"type":"integer"},"tags":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"transactions":{"type":"long"},"type":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}}}}},"settings":{"index":{"number_of_shards":"1","provided_name":"rpa-trans-2020.02.26","creation_date":"1582703183260","requests":{"cache":{"enable":"false"}},"number_of_replicas":"0","uuid":"WslG0Q-YT323WZxNuw_sWw","version":{"created":"5050299"}}}},
```

Comment: you should use `/_search` API .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to issue a request in the format of `GET myindex`. That would give you the mappings and settings of your index.

To read your data, request should looks like `GET myindex/_search`
There are many ways to query data and you can read documentation for the ones that suit your query requirements.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl.html

Answer (score 0):

If you use that code then you can do things like
the_data["rpa-trans-2020.02.26"]["mappings"]

```
the_data = {"rpa-trans-2020.02.26":{"aliases":{},"mappings":{"rpa-trans":{"dynamic":"true","properties":{"@timestamp":{"type":"date"},"@version":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"AreaImpacted":{"type":"keyword"},"AssigneeUserId":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"CreatedByUserId":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"CrossReferenceId":{"type":"keyword"},"EntityName":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"ErrorCode":{"type":"keyword"},"ErrorDescription":{"type":"keyword"},"FailureTransaction":{"type":"integer"},"Initiator":{"type":"keyword"},"InstanceId":{"type":"integer"},"IsApplication":{"type":"keyword"},"ListenerReqEndTime":{"type":"long"},"ListenerReqStartTime":{"type":"long"},"NotQualifiedRequest":{"type":"integer"},"Param1":{"type":"float"},"Param2":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"Param3":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"Param4":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"ProcessName":{"type":"keyword"},"Processes":{"type":"keyword"},"QualifiedRequest":{"type":"integer"},"RetryTrans":{"properties":{"ReasonRequestUnsuccessful":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"RetryAttemptNumber":{"type":"long"},"RetryReason":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}}}},"RobotReqEndTime":{"type":"long"},"RobotReqStartTime":{"type":"long"},"Robots":{"type":"keyword"},"SearchInput":{"type":"keyword"},"SourceApplicationId":{"type":"keyword"},"SourceMachineId":{"type":"keyword"},"StepDescription":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"StepEndTime":{"type":"date"},"StepStartTime":{"type":"date"},"StepStatus":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"SuccessfulTransaction":{"type":"integer"},"TransactionDateTime":{"type":"date","format":"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ"},"TransactionEndTime":{"type":"date"},"TransactionId":{"type":"keyword"},"TransactionMessage":{"type":"keyword"},"TransactionProcessName":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"TransactionProfileName":{"type":"keyword"},"TransactionSource":{"type":"keyword"},"TransactionState":{"type":"keyword"},"TransactionStatus":{"type":"keyword"},"TransactionTitle":{"type":"keyword"},"TransactionType":{"type":"keyword"},"UserId":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"elapsed_execution_time":{"type":"float"},"elapsed_execution_time  ":{"type":"float"},"elapsed_handle_time":{"type":"float"},"elapsed_qualification_time":{"type":"float"},"elapsed_qualification_time ":{"type":"float"},"elapsed_timestamp_start":{"type":"date"},"elapsed_wait_time":{"type":"float"},"manual_proc_time":{"type":"integer"},"process_sla":{"type":"integer"},"tags":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"transactions":{"type":"long"},"type":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}}}}},"settings":{"index":{"number_of_shards":"1","provided_name":"rpa-trans-2020.02.26","creation_date":"1582703183260","requests":{"cache":{"enable":"false"}},"number_of_replicas":"0","uuid":"WslG0Q-YT323WZxNuw_sWw","version":{"created":"5050299"}}}}}
```